# SQL Server: Unique Index on single values of two columns (!!! Not Combination)

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I have a table for teams where each team has two codes. A code for teammembers and a code for the teamleader.

```
TeamId    Name     MemberCode    LeaderCode
--------------------------------------------
1         Team1    CodeXY        CodeXYZ
2         Team2    CodeAB        CodeBC
...
```

There are two unique indexes, one on `MemberCode` and one on `LeaderCode` securing that MemberCodes and LeaderCodes are unique.

But how can I define the not only MemberCodes itself are unqiue, but MemberCodes and LeaderCodes?

No MemberCode should be a LeaderCode.

Someone got an idea?

P.S.: A unique index on the two columns like `Create Unique index UIDX_12 On tbl (MemberCode, LeaderCode)` is no option!

Comment: You can do it with a check constraint.

Comment: Does SQL Server support such check constraints? I was goings to say trigger based solution.

Comment: Yes SQL Server supports check constraints.   Combined with User-Defined functions, they can be quite flexible.

Comment: @TabAlleman, more precisely I was wondering about check constraints using non-deterministic functions?

Comment: Yes, it's been possible since SQL 2000.    http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/using-udf-check-constraint-validate-column

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Tab Alleman!

Answer (score 4):

With this data structure, I think you would have to have a trigger.

You can reformat the data, so you have one table and (at least) three columns:

- TeamId
- Code
- CodeType

Then you can add constraints:

- `codetype` is only 'member' or 'leader'
- `code` is unique
- `teamid` is in the teamid table
- `teamid`/`codetype` is unique

This will allow you to store exactly one of each of these values for each team (assuming that the values are not `NULL`).

In a create table statement, this might look something like:

```
create table . . .
    check codetype in ('member', 'leader'),
    unique(code),
    teamid references teams(teamid),
    unique (teamid, codetype)
    . . .
```

Comment: I came to this solution too, but wonder if this wouldn't mean, that there can be teams without a code?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible.  You could, in turn, fix that by having a teams table that references this table with two columns, one for the member and one for the leader.  The references would be to ids that cannot be `NULL` and cannot be the same.

Comment: But then I would have the same problem as writing the code directly to the columns in the team table.

Comment: @Tobias . . . The uniqueness would be guaranteed by the new table, not the old table.

Comment: The uniqueness of the code-string yes. But not the assigned code in the team-table.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce this constraint with an [indexed view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). Something like:

```
create table dbo.MColumnUnique (
    MemberName int not null,
    LeaderName int not null
)
go
create table dbo.Two (ID int not null primary key,constraint CK_Two_ID CHECK (ID in (1,2)))
go
insert into dbo.Two(ID) values (1),(2)
go
create view dbo.MColumnUnique_Enforcer (Name)
with schemabinding
as
    select
        CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN MemberName ELSE LeaderName END
    from
        dbo.MColumnUnique
            cross join
        dbo.Two
go
create unique clustered index IX_MColumnUnique_Enforcer on dbo.MColumnUnique_Enforcer (Name)
go
insert into dbo.MColumnUnique (MemberName,LeaderName) values (1,2),(3,4) --Works
go
insert into dbo.MColumnUnique (MemberName,LeaderName) values (4,5) --Fails
go
insert into dbo.MColumnUnique (MemberName,LeaderName) values (6,6) --Fails
```

Where hopefully you can see the parallels between my above structure and your tables.

`dbo.Two` is just a generally helpful helper table that contains exactly two rows, and is used to perform a limited unpivot on the data into a single column.

Comment: Instead of a helper table, could you have used a CTE within the view?

Comment: @TabAlleman - unfortunately not. There are quite a lot of restrictions on [indexed views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) and CTEs are on the "not allowed" list. If you have a dedicated numbers table (or any other utility table with a guaranteed set of rows), you can use that instead if you limit yourself to just selecting two rows

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a trigger, but I would use a CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Create a function that takes a varchar parameter (or whatever the datatype you use for MemberCode and LeaderCode), and returns a bit:  0 if there is no LeaderCode or MemberCode that matches the parameter value, or 1 if there is a match.

Then put a check constraint on the table that specifies:

- MemberCode <> LeaderCode AND
- YourFunction(MemberCode) = 0 AND
- YourFunction(LeaderCode) = 0

EDIT based on Damien's comment:

To prevent the function from including the row you just added, you need to also pass the [code] column (which you say is UNIQUE), and not count the row with that value for [code].

Comment: CHECK constraints run in the context of the data as it exists after a DML statement has executed. `YourFunction` will always return `1` since it can "see" the current row that's being checked.